# Blue/Yellow/Red paths after editing Saturation using HSI<--> RGB conversion

Tags: image, colors, rgb, php-gd

I have HSI<--> RGB conversion which works perfectly ok when I try to edit hue by $hue+=$added_value.

But when I try to change saturation by same method($saturation+=added_saturation) using same conversion, the color become brighter but I end up with lots of colored patches. Eg: original white color area have pink patches, some of the original orange color area become blue. I already check resulting RGB value and all are within value of 255. No matter how I try, I still cannot find the problem.

The range of added_value is -100 to 100. 
The ranges used are: 
H : 0 to 360
S : 0 to 100
I : 0 to 255
Here is the conversion I found and used: http://web2.clarkson.edu/class/image_process/RGB%20to%20HSI.pdf

Comment: Are you sure you want to add a value to S where it's zero?